# How can I have Finder mount an SMB share from ssh without confirmation?

Tags: finder, applescript, ssh, smb

In a bigger piece of AppleScript, I need to mount an SMB share. This works:

```
tell application "Finder" to mount volume "smb://server/share"
```

That is, it works without asking questions, from the Script Editor or from a shell running in Terminal (ie. `osascript <my script>`).

But when I try to run the same script while connected to the Mac through ssh from another computer, Finder (I suppose) first asks for confirmation with a dialog on the GUI:

> You are attempting to connect to the server xxx. Click connect to
>   contine.

How can I avoid this confirmation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @klanomath, the confirmation can be disabled by following instructions on this page: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207112

That is, from a terminal:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.NetworkAuthorization AllowUnknownServers -bool YES
```

And then, to undo this change (for better security):

```
sudo defaults delete /Library/Preferences/com.apple.NetworkAuthorization AllowUnknownServers
```